# A vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to read data in from a file, create a critic from the data and then create a vector of pointers to each critic. After I read the data for the first critic and set it to theCritic, I have

```
NightHawks *nightHawkPtr = &theCritic; 
criticPointer.push_back(nightHawkPtr);
```

and then I try to print them out.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < criticPointer.size(); i++)
    {
        criticPointer[i]->text();
    }
```

However, each time the pointer is pushed back, all the pointers point to the same critic.

Comment: Maybe because you have declared only one instance of `theCritic` and you're changing its values? Can you show us more code?

Comment: I am guessing that you are only modifying `theCritic` and pushing new pointers. All those pointers will hold the same memory address thus pointing to the same instance of a critic which is probably the last one.

Comment: I think that is the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix that if I'm reading from an input file that contains an unknown number of critics.

Comment: Why not have a vector of critics instead of critic pointers?

Comment: If `theCritic` is an automatic variable, you're not allowed to dereference the pointer once the variable's lifetime has ended.

Comment: It's for a HW assignment and it has to be a vector of pointers to critics. Our previous assignment used vectors of critics.

Comment: @SamanthaBewley, show the code where you've declared `theCritic`.

Comment: There is only one critic. There is never a `new` critic from the code you have shown. So yes, All the pointers will point to the one critic that exist.

Comment: Could we see the definitions for all the variables here, and a simplified loop showing where you do the push_back?  It looks to me like the code you've posted is correct, so the problem is likely in code you didn't include.

Comment: I declare the critic like this `NightHawks theCritic;` and then i use getLine to read the input from the file and then I use setters to set the input to theCritic

Comment: @SamanthaBewley - What a roundabout way of issuing a pointer homework assignment.  You create a NightHawk by value, and then for some odd reason, forego fundamentals of good C++ design and store pointers to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a new critic when you place it in the vector. Else all the data point to the same memory location.

```
criticPointer.push_back(new NightHawks(theCritic));
```

Better Yet don't store pointers just store the critic value in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

From your code, it looks like you are setting all the pointer values to one instance and just keep changing that instance. You must create new instances everytime the value changes:

```
NightHawks *nhp = new Critic();
```

If you are inserting them into a vector, it is strongly advised to use [shared_ptrs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) so you don't have to worry about freeing memory.

Answer (score 2):

They point to the same critic because you assign them the address of the same variable `theCritic`

```
NightHawks *nightHawkPtr = &theCritic; 
criticPointer.push_back(nightHawkPtr);
```

Moreover if variable theCritic is a local variable then the program can have undefined behaviour because a pointer to the variable becames invalid after the local variable will be destroyed.

Each time you build an object of type critic you should build it in the heap that is you should use operator `new`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment that, `I declare the critic like this NightHawks theCritic; and then i use getLine to read the input from the file and then I use setters to set the input to theCritic`, your problem is that you are changing the contents of the same variable. Create new variables for different critics, assign to them, then push the address into the vector.