# A vector of pointers to strings

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to make a vector of pointers from strings from an input file. I want to add pointers to the strings in the vector if there is not already a pointer to the same string in the vector. If the string is already in the vector, I want the pointer to point to the first instance of the string. I have the following code that doesn't work and I am lost.

```
while(restaurant != stop)
{
    string ratingstr = restaurant.substr(0, 3);
    double rating = atof(ratingstr.c_str());
    string restaurantonly = restaurant.substr(4);           
    // Searching the vector to see if the restaurant is already added
    // if it is, point to the previous instance 
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.size(); i++)
    {
       if (restaurantonly.compare(restaurants[i]) != 0)
       {
          restaurantPointer.push_back(&restaurantonly);

       }
      else // find the resturant in the vector and point to that 
      {
        for (int s = 0; s < i ; s++)
        {
           if (restaurants[s].compare(restaurantonly) == 0)
           {
               restPoint = &restaurants[s];
               restaurantPointer.push_back(restPoint);
            }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a vector of strings, not a vector of pointers to strings (particularly when you're using the same string most of the time).

Comment: Its for a HW assignment and we have to use vectors of pointers to strings.

Comment: `restaurantPointer.push_back(&restaurantonly);` is pushing the same string pointer repeatedly. And the string it points to will go out of scope as soon as your `while` loop exits.

Comment: Stupid assignment then. Checking if something is already present in a vector takes linear time, but checking in (say) an `unordered_set` would take constant time.

Comment: Go back and reread the answers to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177194/a-vector-of-pointers). You are essentially making the same mistake. By the way, this is a bad homework assignment. It could be done more easily and without leaking memory by storing __objects__ instead of __bare pointers__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It puzzles me why students get these awful assignments. OK, ignoring that fact I'll try give you an answer:

```
 restaurantPointer.push_back(&restaurantonly);
```

`restaurtantonly`'s destructor will be called once you leave the while block. it's pointer is therefore no longer valid.

you should use the pointer to a longer lived object, which seems to be the elements of `restaurants`

```
 restaurantPointer.push_back(&restaurants[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you said is true (that `restaurants` is a vector of string pointers), then the following has problems:

```
if (restaurantonly.compare(restaurants[i]) != 0)
{
    restaurantPointer.push_back(&restaurantonly);
}
```

You are comparing a string to a pointer of a string in the if statement. Same deal in your `else`.

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @AlanStokes She's asking about what's wrong with his code, and I'm telling her what's wrong with it...?

Comment: The answer is fine, but the code in the question has so many potential errors that it will take more than this to really help.

Answer (score 0):

**There is a pricipal error:** you are trying to place in the vector a pointer to local variable `restaurantonly` in the while loop. So the approach is invalid.

Also you are trying to compare an object of type `std::string` with `a pointer to std::string`
in statement

```
   if (restaurantonly.compare(restaurants[i]) != 0)
```

Also it would be much better if you would use the comparison operator instead of the member function compare. For example

```
   if ( restaurantonly != *restaurants[i] )
   {
      //...
   }
```